# Best way to compare Pandas dataframe with csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, comparison

I have a number of tests where the Pandas dataframe output needs to be compared with a static baseline file. My preferred option for the baseline file format is the csv format for its readability and easy maintenance within Git. But if I were to load the csv file into a dataframe, and use

```
A.equals(B)
```

where A is the output dataframe and B is the dataframe loaded from the CSV file, inevitably there will be errors as the csv file does not record datatypes and what-nots. So my rather contrived solution is to write the dataframe A into a CSV file and load it back out the same way as B then ask whether they are equal.

Does anyone have a better solution that they have been using for some time without any issues?

Comment: Try looking at the difference between the two dataFrames, the output DataFrame and the one that you load from CSV using: `sum((A != B).any(1))`  Let me know if this works, I can't test this myself as re-creating your situation is not easy

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what exactly does sum((A != B).any(1)) do? I am getting an output of 1. Are you doing a row by row comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a solution that does work for my case by making use of Pandas testing utilities.

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

Then call it from within a try except block where check_dtype is set to False.

```
try:
    assert_frame_equal(A, B, check_dtype=False)
    print("The dataframes are the same.")
except: 
    print("Please verify data integrity.")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the datatypes of the csv file, you can load it as a dataframe with specific datatypes as following:

```
import pandas as pd
B = pd.DataFrame('path_to_csv.csv', dtypes={"col1": "int", "col2": "float64", "col3": "object"} )
```

This will ensure that each column of the csv is read as a particular data type

After that you can just compare the dataframes easily by using

```
A.equals(B)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to compare a lot of pairs, another way to do it would be to compare the hash values of the dataframes instead of comparing each row and column of individual data frames

```
hashA = hash(A.values.tobytes())
hashB = hash(B.values.tobytes())
```

Now compare these two hash values which are just integers to check if the original data frames were same or not.

Be Careful though: I am not sure if the data types of the original data frame would matter or not. Be sure to check that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did this in the past but as the number of files for testing increased, this approach isn't very efficient.

Comment: Yes. I have several use cases. 1) For testing 2) Verifying that existing data is the same between the in-memory dataframe and csv file.

Comment: Another way could be create hash of the dataframes to be compared and then compare those values instead of comparing the original dataframes

Comment: Hmm... How would I go about that? Do you mean a dictionary of sorts? Would there be a performance impact?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include that. Please take a look

Comment: I have tried using hashes. It doesn't quite work as expected because of the difference between 0.0 and 0.

Comment: Yea, that is expected. You would have to ensure that formatting is the same. But that should be easy I think. Especially if you read the csv file columns as integers/floats specifically. Because, I think what you are doing is reading the csv as is (which would be as strings). Otherwise, hash(1.0) and hash(1) are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

`(A != B).any(1)` returns a Series with Boolean values which tells you which rows are equal and which ones aren't ...

Boolean values are internally represented by 1's and 0's, so you can do a sum() to check how many rows were not equal.

```
sum((A != B).any(1))
```

If you get an output of 0, that would mean all rows were equal.